# PHP: regular expression to remove `â` or `â€`?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, special-characters

I use this regular expression to remove all the punctuation marks from a string input,

```
$pg_url = preg_replace("/\W+/", " ", $pg_url);
```

but there are some kind of symbols or special characters I can't remove them, such as

```
 –
```

when I pass this into my db injection, it will either turns into `â` or `â€`

How can I get rid of these strange stuff?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a database charset issue more than anything...

Comment: You've definitely got character encoding problems. Make sure that all parts of your application are using the same character encoding and the problem should go away.

Comment: This "strange stuff" is text that people arrogantly didn't encode in the 7 bits english text happens to get along with. Get your character encodings straight and they don't get mangled.

Comment: thanks so much. got it sorted with iconv now! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those characters are encoded in [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), specifically [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

You may want to consider using the [iconv family](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.iconv.php) of functions to convert them into some other encoding (e.g. plain ASCII first).