# Is there a PHP function to fix this?

Tags: php, encoding

"â€œExcuse me, I hope this isnâ€™t weird or anything,"

How can I fix the encoding on this?

Comment: That depends on where it came from and what it is. In general, once you have real [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), you can't magically fix it. If you're just not handling encoding correctly somewhere along the way, you can fix it at the appropriate location to prevent it from becoming mojibake in the first place.

Comment: Can you describe the issue in more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're running into is the result of the data being written in one encoding, and interpreted as being another. You need to make sure that you're requesting input to be in the same format that you're expecting it to be in. I recommend just sticking with UTF-8 the whole way through unless you need to avoid multibyte characters, in which case you might want to look at forcing ASCII.

Make sure you're telling PHP to use UTF-8 internally:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

And make sure that you are telling the browser to expect UTF-8 encoded text, both in headers…

```
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

…and in your meta tags (html5 below)…

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Setting this will tell the browser to sent UTF-8 encoded content to you when a form is submitted, and it'll interpret the results you send back as UTF-8 as well.

You should also make sure both your database storage and connection encoding are in UTF-8 as well. Usually as long as it is just a dumb data store (i.e. it won't be manipulating or interpreting the data in any way) it doesn't matter, but it's better to have it all right than run into problems with it later.

Answer (score 3):

The [`iconv`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function is generally able to deal with this sort of encoding issue.

Comment: `iconv` can help, but only if you know you need to convert from one encoding to another. It doesn't seem like Webnet is familiar enough with the matter to know what encoding he wants is converting from or to.

Answer (score 1):

See this thread: [PHP: regular expression to remove `â` or `â€`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761586/php-regular-expression-to-remove-a-or-a)

Comment: I'd rather not use a regular expression, but something that can overall fix all encoding issues.

Answer (score 1):

What are your php settings??

You can configure php to encode the out of strings, in most of case utf8 it's recommended and also you must have a Content-Type tag in your html page

Answer (score 0):

Also if I may add aside from those points stated above, if you are saving the data to database tables, the tables and columns (and maybe the database itself too) should have utf8_general_ci so that it can handle multibyte characters.

I also issue this query **set names 'utf8'** before running any query.

Comment: The collation (like utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci) doesn't matter for anything other than ordering. You probably mean the "CHARACTER SET", as MySQL refers to it should be set to "utf8".

Comment: stumbled across this answer and comments.... you should actually use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` !!     mysql's utf8  only supports up to 3 bytes... utf8mb4 supports the full 4 bytes.     the general collation is also somewhat broken    the unicode collation follows the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the right solution is [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

string **mb_convert_encoding** ( string $str , string $to_encoding [, mixed $from_encoding ] )

Converts the character encoding of string str to to_encoding from optionally from_encoding.