# Mojibake issue in XML retrieved over cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl, encoding, mojibake

I'm retrieving [this XML feed](http://feeds.feedburner.com/HammersInTheHeart?format=xml) over PHP cURL and outputting it in a textarea on my page. The problem is, it's coming back full of mojibake characters. The feed itself is fine; it's only when output on my page that the chars appear.

Pound signs (£) are coming back as Â£, for example.

I've tried throwing UTF-8 at the issue, as suggested in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940867/is-there-a-php-function-to-fix-this).

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

And in the HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and even by outputting the cURL response via `utf8_encode()`, yet still they persist.

```
$ch = curl_init($feed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
echo '<textarea>'.utf8_encode($xml).'</textarea>';
```

I even tried swapping these chars out, but that didn't cut it.

```
$xml = strtr($xml, array('Â£' => ''));
```

Am I powerless here, or is there something I can do?

Comment: Have you tried [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't. From/to which encoding?

Answer (score 1):

Use `htmlentities` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) before displaying the XML content in an HTML page, also change `$ch` to `$xml` in that call, so:

```
echo '<textarea>'.htmlentities($xml).'</textarea>';
```

Comment: Thanks, but this renders the XML unparsable as it converts `<` into `&lt;`

Comment: Displaying it in a text area is different from parsing it... if you want to parse it you need to use the PHP XML parser on the unmodified content

Answer (score 1):

`utf8_encode()` will treat the input as latin-1 and convert it to utf-8. If the input is utf-8 this will be a double encoding - that's what you're seeing.

Check the XML string you're fetching from the URL. The encoding of an XML file is usually in the XML processing instruction:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document-element/>
```

Loaded into DOM, XMLReader or SimpleXML it will always be converted to UTF-8. Any value you read using the APIs will be UTF-8.

If you like to output the UTF-8 XML into the textarea of your HTML page you need to escape the special characters.

```
echo '<textarea>'.htmlspecialchars($xml).'</textarea>';
```

This will escape characters like `<` and `>`, but this is needed. Imagine the XML containing the string `</textarea>`. This would break your HTML page. The browser will decode `&lt;` and the other entities before displaying them.

Comment: Thank you, I will explore this further.